# How to address email to a professor who prefers informality?

Tags: etiquette, email

How should I address an email to a professor who hates being called "Professor ___" or "Dr. ____?" He has made it very clear to students that he prefers to be referred to by his first name in person, but I have been told time and time again that one should be more formal when writing emails. Is this always true, or should I simply follow how he prefers to be addressed in person?

Comment: With rare exceptions, if someone tells you that they want to be treated a certain way, you should treat them that way, no matter what anyone else says or thinks.

Comment: If you are very worried about it, in your first email you can use the polite and very English "If I may" so:

Comment: Do you really have to use his name at all?  I seldom do, with people I know, just starting with something like "Hi",

Comment: echoing @jamesqf - what's wrong with a simple "Good morning/Good afternoon/Good evening"? You're over thinking this

Comment: Email already comes with To: and From: fields, so salutations and signatures are anachronisms.

Comment: To be more formal in written communication, stop using ‘email’ as a [count noun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Count_noun).

Comment: @JeffE Just out of curiosity, could you name such an exception?

Comment: Related question of mine on Workplace S.E.: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/95932/how-to-respond-to-request-to-use-a-first-name

Comment: @Henrik "Please take this gun and shoot me in the face."

Comment: @KeithMcClary The extra effort to greet someone within the letter was already matter of courtesy before email was invented. (Snail-mail has "from" and "to" fields, on the envelop.) It's just that these kinds of courtesies have become less emphasized.

Comment: @ Keith McClary: Though not all email addresses are the person's name.  In my CS department, faculty email was firstname+initial@cs.school.edu, students were initial+lastname, unless you were friends with someone who could change it.

Comment: To add to the great answers below: One thing is addressing the professor who prefers to be addressed by his/her first name, but it's another thing to talk about the same professor. E.g. I would say "Hi, Mary" when I meet the professor, but "I met professor Smith" if I mention it later. Also, when I mention other academics, I mention the formal title, so she knows that I'm doing the same about her, eg. "Mary, what do you think about the new paper from professor Saitō's group?"

Comment: One of my professors has the same thing. He likes to be addressed: "Dear Lucky,"

Answer (score 68, accepted):

**If the professor explicitly says not to call him by his last name, then don't.** It would actually be more impolite to ignore his request in order to conform to some abstract "formality" rules.

However, even if you are addressing your professor by his first name, you can still preserve some degree of formality. Some common norms include:

- do not use slang
- avoid excessive contractions (e.g. use *have not* instead of *haven't)*
- use your full name in the signature
- be polite

In general, the rule of thumb is to be respectful and professional in your communications. Sometimes that includes addressing the person as "Professor X" or "Dr. X", but it does not have to. Just make sure you sound polite!

Comment: Agree, except for the part of _use your full name in the signature_ - at least when you know each other, there is no need to add your surname, in my opinion.

Comment: @Mark On the contrary. I always use my full name on the off-chance there's another Sean the professor I'm talking to is working with.

Comment: @SeanRoberson Seen this way it makes sense. My first name isn't very frequent.

Comment: @SeanRoberson yes, but as long as you have a school email and the school email system tells the professor who you are, that doesn't really matter either.

Comment: Professor X ... Now I'm thinking about posting a question regarding the relevance of politeness in the context of telepaths.

Comment: Haha, I once had two students in my class with the same first and last names.  Fortunately, they had quite different handwriting; so in my record of their assignment marks, they were known as "John Doe with the curly writing" and "John Doe with the square writing".

Comment: As a non-native english speaker, I wasn't aware that contractions were seen as informal or impolite

Comment: @MechMK1 : In my view, they aren't. One would only use the full form in writing for emphasis or when trying to be ultra-formal (I certainly wouldn't "avoid contractions" when writing to a professor I didn't know.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem : I was at uni with "Clever Sue Pierce" and "Pretty Sue Pierce" (the latter referred to herself as "Thick Sue Pierce").

Comment: @MartinBonner I would only split up contractions when I want to emphasize the negation. "I assure you, I did *not* support this desicion", as an example

Comment: My name is Bob Brown.  I share it with about a zillion other Anglophones.  There are ten zillion Bobs and at least that many Browns.  If there is *any possibility* of confusion, use both names.

Comment: @MartinBonner  I was at school with Diane Darling and Diane Love.  They were in the same dormitory room, and so shared a phone number.  "Is this Diane Love?"  "No, this is Diane, darling!"

Answer (score 37):

Rules exist to serve people, not people to serve rules. The default is formality, because if you don't know how someone wants to be called, then formality shows respect. If you do know how someone wants to be called, them calling them that shows respect. Don't confuse the means for the end. Formality is the means, respect is the end.

Comment: This may be the best answer, especially at a conceptual level.

Comment: +1 I saw a many once declare that he held doors open for women, whether they liked it or not, because his mother taught him to. He obviously missed the point of the lesson.

Comment: @EllenSpertus to tell the truth, I do not get the point of holding doors open or of purposely not holding doors open.

Answer (score 28):

I would suggest that you use the name/term/concept that the professor signs his initial reply to you with as the introduction to follow up e-mails. This approach ensures that you are always **correct** and **formal** in your **initial contact** and can be **informal** in the **subsequent contacts** if the reply allowed you to do so. See the following e-mail headers/footers as an example:

Original Contact

```
Dear Prof. FancyPants,

...

Kind Regards,
Hopeful Grad Student
```

First Reply

```
Dear Hopeful Grad Student,

...

Cheers,
John
```

Your Reply

```
Hi John,

...

Cheers,
Andy
```

I hope that the above illustrates how I would treat your situation.

Comment: Replying with the person's signature is generally the safest bet anywhere unless you know otherwise.

Comment: I agree with this one.  Please call me 'Santa' from now on.

Comment: One problem with this is that often professor's won't give you a signature you can use for future contact. For example, professors who sign with just an initial ("-B") or initials ("-BXJ"), or more commonly, if they just don't sign their name at all. Or if they sign with their full name, etc.

Comment: @6005 Dear -BXJ, dear 6005, … :-D

Comment: @MadPhysicist "unless you know otherwise" which is exactly the case here.

Comment: @Mast. Actually you don't know what the professor's signature is. I bet it's the informal name he wants students to use though.

Comment: @6005 My understanding is that that is often a way to *not* signal that a person is OK with more informality while also not having to sign emails as "Sincerely, Professor/Dr. X" -- social norms for how one is addressed by others and how one refers to oneself are different.

Answer (score 18):

In general: Do not be scared and do not think too much about it.

Professors are people as well and often they are way more interested in the content of your mail than in formalities. Especially when they have a lot of work, they do not even have the time to judge how you begin your e-mails ;).

Here is a cartoon how much time professors need for e-mails and how much time students need:

[image: PhD comics on e-mails of professors and students]
http://phdcomics.com/comics.php?f=1047

You're on the right side and overthinking the formalities. Your professor is on the left side and just reading the important parts of your e-mail (so make sure that you do not hide your question in too much text) before replying.

Answer (score 11):

> **who hates being called "Professor ___" or "Dr. ____?" He has made it very clear to students that he prefers to be referred to by his first name**

It seems he did not make it clear enough to all of the students. If he **hates** it and makes it **very clear**, it sounds even desperate! Please, do him the favor and address him as he prefers:

"Hi John" or "Hello John" or "Dear John"

That's what *he* explicitly prefers. And btw. as soon as you are around researchers (grad student and higher), you will address most people you meet at conferences etc as "hi FirstName".

Professors are humans as well. General rules are nice but do not hold every time. Here is one of the exceptions.

Comment: If the OP wants a little formality, I'd use "Hello John" rather than "Hi John".  I might even write "Dear John," - but then I wrote letters starting "Dear Mum," in my youth.

Comment: But that's the point! It's not about what the OP want's, but what the professor wants. Still, true, he can also use "hello" or "dear".

Comment: There are dozens if not hundreds of questions an this stack to which the answer can be summarised as: "professors are human".

Answer (score 5):

If you are very worried about it, in your first email you can use the polite and very English "If I may".

So for example:

> Dear Sarah (if I may),  I am writing to you to ask about...

It signals your commitment to formality, but also takes your Prof's preference into account. If they sign their response with their full name or say something like "of course you may!", you're set.

Comment: This kind of language always strikes me as overly formal and awkward writing in modern english, I really try to avoid it because it doesn't make the best impression. But I've never really found a better alternative.

Answer (score 2):

There are possibly two issues here. The first is accommodation of the professor's wishes. As a default, address him however he wants. It is better to be respectful than formal, as all the other answers point out.

The other (possible) issue (pointed out anecdotally in @RadishQueen's answer), is that students may feel very uncomfortable addressing a professor like that. If this is indeed part of the motivation for the question, the solution is never to disrespect the professor, but you can always mention to him that it makes you very uncomfortable to address him so informally. He may decide to ignore your feelings on the matter or come up with a reasonable compromise. In either case, respect the professor's wishes.

Answer (score 0):

As a programmer, the vast majority of most of emails I send in a professional context are of the following format :

```
Hi Tom,

...

Kind regards,

John Slegers
```

At least in my sector, pretty much everyone uses this format these days, whether communicating with clients, with subcontractors, with our boss, etc. At least in the IT sector, formal emails are the exception rather than the standard.

As a student, I'd inclined to be a bit more formal when contacting a professor in at least my initial email, but not in your case. Considering he explicitly expressed his desired to be referred to by his first name in real life, I would not be any more formal in my emails to your professor than I am in my corporate emails.

Answer (score 0):

I'd likely just use his name, as in

> Tom,
>
> I'd like to ...
>
> Regards,
> Paul Smith

The option of writing

> Regards,
> Paul

and putting your full name into signature/From line seems not as much informal as familiar to me.  Probably not the best idea.

Also, your informality should only extend to the degree the professor has specified as desired, so don't start with

> Yo teach,
>
> ...

Either way, make sure that the From/To lines contain the full name of yourself and the professor.  If there is a formally required title for your professor, it should be added there.  This is the "mail envelope".  While you won't likely enfuriate a secretary by being less than formal on the envelope of an *Email*, I think it is a good strategy to show respect in the *content* by using the amount of informality desired, and in the *envelope* by using the amount of formality due.