# Switching from formal to informal in email

Tags: email

I have contacted a supervisor (call him Dr Thomas Riddle) to chat about an advertised PhD project, writing

> Dear Dr Riddle,

to which he replied with

> Hi Luis,

and he signed off with

> Tom.

In my reply, should I stick with

> Dear Dr Riddle

or is it ok (or better?) to write

> Dear Tom/Thomas

Comment: Whatever you decide, don't use "Thomas" when the professor has signed with "Tom."  Although my birth certificate says Robert, I much prefer to be called Bob, or maybe Dr. Brown, depending on the circumstance.  It would annoy me if I signed "Bob" and were then addressed as "Robert."  I suspect I'm not alone.

Comment: I suggest searching our archives, this has been discussed many times. For example [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/84410/is-it-ok-to-call-a-professor-by-his-first-name-when-he-she-signs-emails-by-only) and [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/175301/when-to-switch-from-hello-dear-professor-x-to-hi-x-in-email) and [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/98679/how-to-address-email-to-a-professor-who-prefers-informality).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there's no wrong choice.

! would reply starting with Dr. Riddle (without the dear) and sign as Luis.

In the next round (if there is one) or if you become his student, then move to Tom, which is what he probably expects at that point.

Comment: This seems like a good balance. But there are cultural considerations. I'd guess this works in US or UK, but maybe not some other places that expect a more formal response from students. There is a story (apocryphal?) about a famous German mathematician who told his student (and mistress) that it wasn't necessary to call him "Dr. Professor X" when they were in alone in private. (or is it "Professor Dr." - I can never remember).

Comment: @Buffy The professor's first response is an implicit invitation to informality.

Comment: Yes, I agree. But I have my own cultural understandings.